# Command line parsing in Tcl

Tags: parsing, tcl, command-line-arguments

I have a script that will require many short and long options and was wondering what would be the most efficient way to parse the command line arguments. Using for-each and if-else would make the code too long and difficult to modify, so is there be any standard function that can help me (something like getopt for C)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discussed this [four days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110082/how-to-create-tcl-proc-with-hyphen-flag-arguments) and a few suggestions were posted.

There is also the [cmdline](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html) package in Tcllib.