# How to use getopts in TCL

Tags: tcl

I want to use get opts to run for a file name.

I want to be able to type in a command like this:

```
tclsh -f application_report.txt delete_file.tcl
```

and then be able to print in my script:

```
application_report.txt
```

Comment: Did you search for previous Q&A? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198942/command-line-parsing-in-tcl

Comment: I use `cmdline` from tcllib,

Comment: cmdline docs: https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the name of the script first, because that's processed by `tclsh` itself to know what command to run. Options come after that. (In fact, `tclsh` does accept a small number of options itself, but you hardly ever want to provide them except when auto-detection of the script's encoding is going wrong.)

As you're using the [`cmdline` package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.md), here's how to do it:

Script:

```
package require cmdline

# Description of the options
set OPTIONS {
    {f.arg   "output file"}
}

# Part of the usage message; feel free to tweak
set USAGE ": tclsh delete_file.tcl \[options]\noptions:"

# Initialise some defaults; totally not necessary...
dict set opts {
    f "default_file.txt"
}

# Process the options
try {
    array set opts [cmdline::getoptions argv $OPTIONS $USAGE]
} trap {CMDLINE USAGE} {msg} {
    puts stderr $msg
    exit 1
}

# Now, we can just use them; $::argv is everything not processed
set filename $opts(f)
# ...
```

How to call:

```sh
tclsh delete_file.tcl -f application_report.txt
```

If you use a `#!` line at the top of the script, you'll probably want to adjust the `USAGE` line.