# How to create Tcl Procedure with options?

Tags: tcl, procedure, optional-parameters

I want to create tcl procedures with some options. I know procedures with arguments and optional arguments, but don't know options. For example, if I am calling my procedure arith in following three ways (-add for addition, -sub for subtraction):

```
1) arith 10 5 
2) arith -add 10 5   or   arith 10 5 -add
3) arith -sub 10 5   or   arith 10 5 -sub
```

Respectively output should be 1) 15 (by default it should add), 2) 15,   3) 5

How to write this procedure in Tcl? I am new to tcl, please suggest me some online material or book for Tcl.

Comment: See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110082/how-to-create-tcl-proc-with-hyphen-flag-arguments. The asker wanted tab completion and wasn't satisfied, but the answers should be helpful to you.

Comment: Or maybe not, on second thought. Your scheme is a bit unorthodox. Usually in Tcl one would use a subcommand operator (arith add ..., arith sub ...) or a regular option (arith ..., arith -operator add ..., arith -operator sub ...). The above mentioned answer should help you get started, anyway.

Comment: Thanks Peter.. Your link is helpful..

Answer (score 5):

Complex argument parsing can be done with the [`cmdline` package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html), which is part of Tcllib. The key command is `::cmdline::getoptions`, which extracts the options from a variable and returns a dictionary describing them. It also modifies the variable so it contains just the arguments left over.

```
package require cmdline
proc arith args {
    set options {
        {op.arg "add" "operation to apply (defaults to 'add')"}
    }
    array set parsed [::cmdline::getoptions args $options]
    if {[llength $args] != 2} {
        return -code error "wrong # args: must be \"arith ?-op operation? x y\""
    }
    switch $parsed(op) {
        add {return [::tcl::mathop::+ {*}$args]}
        sub {return [::tcl::mathop::- {*}$args]}
        default {
            return -code error "Unknown -op \"$parsed(op)\": must be add or sub"
        }
    }
}
```

Demonstrating usage (including some error cases):

```
% arith 
wrong # args: must be "arith ?-op operation? x y"
% arith 2 3
5
% arith -op sub 2 3
-1
% arith -op mult 2 3
Unknown -op "mult": must be add or sub
```

The main thing to be aware of is that the options descriptor takes the names of options *without a leading `-`* and *with* `.arg` on the end if you want to have an argument passed as well.

Comment: this is a pretty good response. I'll have to test it to see if the proc works in prefix and postfix. Using the cmdline package was kinda cool but in reality not very ideal for performance etc.Of course the problem is in the question.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to options, it's a good idea to use even number of arguments

```
 -op add -values {10 5}
 -op sub -values {10 5}
```

With this, you can put the arguments into array as,

```
array set aArgs $args
```

where `args` is nothing but arguments passed to procedure.

```
proc arith {args} {
        if {[catch {array set aArgs $args} err]} {
            puts "Error : $err"
             return 0
        }
    if {![info exists aArgs(-op)] || ![info exists aArgs(-values)] || [llength $aArgs(-values)]!=2} {
        puts "Please pass valid args"
        return 0
    }
    set x [lindex $aArgs(-values) 0]
    set y [lindex $aArgs(-values) 1]
    switch $aArgs(-op) { 
        "add" { 
            puts [expr {$x+$y}]
        }
        "sub" { 
            puts [expr {$x-$y}]     
        }
    }
}
arith -op add -values {10 5}
```

Comment: Consider doing default arguments by calling `array set aArgs {-op add -values {0 0}}` (or something like that) prior to parsing `$args`.

Comment: Use `lassign` to assign to x and y

Comment: Can't we do it by taking arguments separately. Like: proc arith {op1 op2}. Instead of proc arith {args}

Answer (score 0):

In this example... I'm assuming that the operator is either the first or last option. The value would be `-add` or `add`. Just make the changes.

There is an optimization in the computation... to use lrange and ::mathop::.

```
proc arith args {
    if {[llength $args] != 3} {
        return -code error "wrong # args: must be \"arith ?-op operation? x y\""
    }
    set isadd [lsearch $args add]
    set issub [lsearch $args sub]
    if {$isadd != -1 && $issub == -1} {
        return [expr [lindex $args 1] + [lindex $args [expr $isadd == 0 ? 2: 0]]]
    }
    if {$issub != -1 && $isadd == -1} {
        return [expr [lindex $args [expr $issub == 0 ? 1: 0]] - [lindex $args [expr $issub == 0 ? 2: 1]]]
    }
    return -code error "Unknown -op must be add or sub"
}
```

example:

```
#arith add 1 2 3
#arith add sub 2
puts [arith add 1 2]
puts [arith 1 2 add]

puts [arith sub 1 2]
puts [arith 1 2 sub]
```

The two error examples were commented out because I need a catch instead... but it really depends on the big picture and how reusable it's intended to be.

```
proc arith args {
    if {[llength $args] != 3} {
        return -code error "wrong # args: must be \"arith ?-op operation? x y\""
    }
    set isadd [lsearch $args -add]
    set issub [lsearch $args -sub]
    if {$isadd != -1 && $issub == -1} {
        return [::tcl::mathop::+ {*}[lrange $args [expr $isadd == 0] [expr ($isadd == 0) + 1]]]
    }
    if {$issub != -1 && $isadd == -1} {
        return [::tcl::mathop::- {*}[lrange $args [expr $issub == 0] [expr ($issub == 0) + 1]]]
    }
    return -code error "Unknown -op must be add or sub"
}
```