# how to write a tcl procedure with default values and options?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to write a tcl procedure which does the following -

```
proc myProc {arg1 def1} {arg2 def2} {
...
...
}

tcl> myProc -arg1 val1 -arg2 val2
arg1 variable has val1
arg2 variable has val2

tcl> myProc -arg1 val1
arg1 variable has val1
arg2 variable has def2

tcl> myProc -?
myProc -arg1 <value1> -arg2 <value2>
arg1 - required argument [default value is 10]
arg2 - optional argument [default value is 20]
help - print this message
?    - print this message
```

Is this possible in tcl?

I looked up some of the questions that have been asked and what I see is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31110082/how-to-create-tcl-proc-with-hyphen-flag-arguments?rq=1). This does partially what I require but I couldn't find anything that would help me solve my problem. Please guide me!

Answer (score 3):

Read the [proc](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/proc.htm) man page carefully: the list of arguments has to be a single list. You were thinking about this:

```
% proc myproc {{a 42} {b 54}} { puts "a=$a b=$b" }
% myproc
a=42 b=54
% myproc 1
a=1 b=54
% myproc 1 2
a=1 b=2
```

Note that the first argument is assigned to `a` -- you cannot provide a value for `b` and use the default value for `a` with this method.

To use command-line-like options, the simplest way is this:

```
% proc myproc {args} {
    array set data [list -a 42 -b 54 {*}$args]
    puts "a=$data(-a) b=$data(-b)"
}
% myproc
a=42 b=54
% myproc -a 1
a=1 b=54
% myproc -b 2
a=42 b=2
% myproc -b 2 -a 3
a=3 b=2
% myproc -c 4
a=42 b=54
```

One problem with this method is that you must pass an even number of arguments, or `array set` will throw an error:

```
% myproc 12
list must have an even number of elements
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a utility function for this years ago. The arguments have the same syntax as `proc` but it generates procs that work the way you describe. The code is simple:

```
proc optproc {name args script} {
    proc $name args [
        string map [list ARGS $args SCRIPT $script] {
            foreach var {ARGS} {
                set [lindex $var 0] [lindex $var 1]
            }

            foreach {var val} $args {
                set [string trim $var -] $val
            }

            SCRIPT
        }
    ]
}
```

What the code does above is basically call `proc` with two foreach loops injected to the function body to process the arguments.

With this you can declare your function like this:

```
optproc myProc {{arg1 def1} {arg2 def2}} {
    # you can use arg1 and arg2 just like a regular proc:

    puts $arg1
    puts $arg2
}
```

Which you can then use the way you wanted:

```
myProc                      ;# default values for arg1 and arg2
myProc -arg1 foo            ;# default values for arg2
myProc -arg2 bar            ;# default values for arg1
myProc -arg1 foo -arg2 bar
```

For more info and discussion on this you can read the wiki page: http://wiki.tcl.tk/20066

For even more flexible proc argument processing you can use a while loop: http://wiki.tcl.tk/16032

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tcllib module [cmdline](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html). On [wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/784) you can find example how to use this module with proc.

```
proc printdata args {
    array set param [::cmdline::getoptions args {\
                    {page.arg  1 "current page"}
                    {pages.arg 1 "number of pages"}
                    } "printdata ?options? Data"]
    if {1 != [llength $args]} {
            return -code error "No data given"
    }
    set param(data) [lindex $args 0]
    # processing here
    parray param
}

% printdata -pages 2 -- "--Head data to print--"
param(data)  = --Head data to print--
param(page)  = 1
param(pages) = 2

% printdata -?
printdata ?options? Data
 -page value          current page <1>
 -pages value         number of pages <1>
 -help                Print this message
 -?                   Print this message
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your valuable inputs. I have written the following code which helps me achieve what I want -

***Code***

```
proc argsParser args {

    set args [string map { - "" } $args]

    if {[expr [llength $args] % 2] != 0 } {
        puts "Wrong Arguments :: $args "
        return "For Help :: argsParser -?";
    }

    switch $args {
        h -
        help -
        ? { puts "Usage :: argParser -arg1 val1 -arg2 val2" 
              puts "arg1 :: Number"
              puts "arg2 :: Number"
        }
        default {
            set arg1 10 ;
            set arg2 20 ;

            set args [string map { - "" } $args]
            for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $args]} { incr i 2} {
                set a [lindex $args $i]
                if { $a != "arg1" && $a != "arg2" } {
                    return "Unknown Args :: $a - For Help :: argsParser -?";
                }
                set b [lindex $args [expr $i+1]]
                set $a $b 
            }

            puts "arg1 - $arg1"
            puts "arg2 - $arg2"
        }   
    }   
}
```

***Result***

```
tcl> argsParser -arg1 20 -arg4 40
Unknown Args :: arg4 - For Help :: argsParser -?

tcl> argsParser -arg1 20 -arg2 40
arg1 - 20
arg2 - 40
```