# How to set an expect script with options

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I am using expect to restart a TCP server if it stops working. The server itself has multiples parameters I can set (it is a python code).

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout -1

spawn python2.7 -u gfsk_rx.py -d "rtl_sdr=0" -s 1000000 -f 437500000 -b 9600 -w 25000 -g 1 -o "/dev/null" -i "127.0.0.1" -p 7000 

expect "Press Enter to quit: file_descriptor_sink"
send -- 'r'
```

As you can see I have multiple parameters (-d, -s, -f, etc) I can set in my python code.

I want to know if I can also run my expect code by doing something like

```
while true; do expect my_script.exp --device "uhd=0"; done
```

And this would change my -d "rtl_sdr=0" to "uhd=0"

I have tried to use the "$1", "$2", etc but it didn't work. I want to know if it is possible to do this, but I was not able to find a solution.

Comment: Why not add that logic to the script when you’re parsing and setting the parameters

Comment: u can also use [tag:pexpect] since u r already using python. :)

Comment: @Eric you mean by doind "$1" for example? I have tried it and didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Q contains useful info relevant to what you're doing: [how to write a tcl procedure with default values and options?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39260773/7552)

The command line arguments can be found in the global `$argv` list. You can loop over that list, testing the values. [This chapter of the Tcl tutorial](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl38.html) provides just a touch more detail.

The [`cmdline` package from tcllib](https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html) could also be useful for you.

Comment: This is not really an answer, more of an extended comment.